# How to resize the width of the bar graph in R plotly

Tags: r, plotly, bar-chart

How can I ensure that the 'gap' between 1st and 3rd Jan is equal to the size of the bar in 1st Jan?

The current plot is misleading to readers as the gap for 2 Jan should be as wide as the bar in 1st Jan.

```
library(plotly)
library(lubridate)

dat  = data.frame(a =c( dmy("1/1/22") , dmy("3/1/22"),dmy("6/1/22")) , b = c(1,1,4))

> dat
           a b
1 2022-01-01 1
2 2022-01-03 1
3 2022-01-06 4

plot_ly(dat , x = ~a, y = ~b , type = "bar")
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set `bargap` (between or equal to 0 and 1) in `layout()` to adjust the gap between bars.

```r
dat %>%
  plot_ly(x = ~a, y = ~b, type = "bar") %>%
  layout(bargap = 0.5)
```

[image]